# How do I use multiple polls in telegram-python-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a bot with 10 quizes for Telegram. The API I'm using is https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot. The problem is I can't create the second question. Creating different function and handler for it doesn't work since it relies on one handler. I'm not experienced with this library yet so I'd like help^^ (I could use a workaround with variables like questionnumber but that will only break things since this bot is going to be used by more than 1 people)
My code right now:

```py
import logging
import time
from time import sleep
from telegram import (
    Poll,
    ParseMode,
    KeyboardButton,
    KeyboardButtonPollType,
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup,
    ReplyKeyboardRemove,
    InlineKeyboardButton,
    InlineKeyboardMarkup
)
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
    PollAnswerHandler,
    PollHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
)
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Розпочати", callback_data='start'),
        ],
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Інформація", callback_data='info'),
        ],
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    """Inform user about what this bot can do"""
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Ласкаво просимо до нашого чат-боту "Критичне мислення й усвідомлення споживаємої інформації". Ми підготували для тебе завдання, де тобі допомогатимуть знання отримані від нашого проекту. Тобі зустрічатимуться різні новини, але не забувай, що фейки можуть підстерігати тебе на кожному кроці, тому покладайся тільки на свое критичне мислення.\n\nНатисніть "Розпочати", щоб почати опитування, або "Інформація", щоб дізнатися про проект',
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
def quizquest1(update, context):
    """Send a predefined poll"""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Варіанти відповідей", callback_data='startquiz1'),
        ],
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.reply_text('Почнемо! На фейсбуці ви побачили пост "Довгоочікуване відкриття Starbucks в Україні! Лайкни цей пост і отримай безкоштовне термогорнятко". Виглядає пристойно, під постом кілька лайків від ваших друзів. Щоб почати опитування, натисніть кнопку.', reply_markup=reply_markup)
def quiz1(update,context):
    timer=10
    questions = ["Лайкну також, а раптом пощастить", "Мені не цікаво, але пошейрю друзям", "Нічого, виглядає як обман"]
    message = update.reply_poll(
        "Що ви зробите?", questions, type=Poll.QUIZ, correct_option_id=2, is_anonymous=True
    )
    # Save some info about the poll the bot_data for later use in receive_quiz_answer
    payload = {
        message.poll.id: {"chat_id": update.chat.id, "message_id": message.message_id}
    }
    context.bot_data.update(payload)
def quizanswer1(update, context):
    """Close quiz after three participants took it"""
    # the bot can receive closed poll updates we don't care about
    if update.poll.is_closed:
        return
    if update.poll.total_voter_count == 1:
        try:
            quiz_data = context.bot_data[update.poll.id]
        # this means this poll answer update is from an old poll, we can't stop it then
        except KeyError:
            return
        context.bot.delete_message(quiz_data["chat_id"], quiz_data["message_id"])
        answertext='У брендів такого рівня є офіційні сторінки зі спеціальною позначкою. І хоча ймовірність проведення такої акції все ж існує, перед тим, як брати участь, перевірте, чи є ця сторінка офіційною.'
        if update.poll.options[2]['voter_count'] == 1:
            keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Наступне питання", callback_data='startquiz2'),
            ]
            ]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            context.bot.send_message(quiz_data["chat_id"], "Вірно! {0}".format(answertext), reply_markup=reply_markup)
        else:
            keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Спробувати знову", callback_data='startquiz1'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Почати спочатку", callback_data='start')
            ]
            ]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            context.bot.send_message(quiz_data["chat_id"], "Невірно! {0} Можете спробувати відповісти на питання знову з цією інформацією або почати спочатку.".format(answertext), reply_markup=reply_markup)
def quizanswer2(update,context):
    if update.poll.is_closed:
        return
    if update.poll.total_voter_count == 1:
        try:
            quiz_data = context.bot_data[update.poll.id]
        # this means this poll answer update is from an old poll, we can't stop it then
        except KeyError:
            return
        context.bot.delete_message(quiz_data["chat_id"], quiz_data["message_id"])
        answertext='Людина з критичним мисленням здатна до відстоювання власної думки, зміни поглядів під впливом вагомих аргументів, а також — «погодження не погоджуватися».'
        if update.poll.options[2]['voter_count'] == 1:
            keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Наступне питання", callback_data='startquiz3'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Попереднє питання", callback_data='startquiz1'),
            ]
            ]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            context.bot.send_message(quiz_data["chat_id"], "Вірно! {0}".format(answertext), reply_markup=reply_markup)
        else:
            keyboard = [
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Спробувати знову", callback_data='startquiz2'),
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton("Попереднє питання", callback_data='startquiz1'),
                InlineKeyboardButton("Почати спочатку", callback_data='start')
            ]
            ]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            context.bot.send_message(quiz_data["chat_id"], "Невірно! {0} Можете спробувати відповісти на питання знову з цією інформацією або почати спочатку.".format(answertext), reply_markup=reply_markup)
def quizquest2(update, context):
    """Send a predefined poll"""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Варіанти відповідей", callback_data='startquiz1'),
        ],
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.reply_text('Ваша улюблена авторка написала статтю, висновки якої у корені відрізняються від вашої думки з цього питання.', reply_markup=reply_markup)
def quiz2(update,context):
    timer=10
    questions = ["Яке розчарування. Більше не буду її читати, бо варто оточувати себе однодумцями", "Вона відома та розумна, отже знає більше за мене. Мені варто змінити свої погляди", "Що ж, так буває. Люди не зобов’язані погоджуватися в усьому"]
    message = update.reply_poll(
        "Ваша реакція?", questions, type=Poll.QUIZ, correct_option_id=2, is_anonymous=True
    )
    # Save some info about the poll the bot_data for later use in receive_quiz_answer
    payload = {
        message.poll.id: {"chat_id": update.chat.id, "message_id": message.message_id}
    }
    context.bot_data.update(payload)

def buttons(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()
    if query.data == "start":
        print('a')
        questionnumber=1
        quizquest1(query.message, context)
    elif query.data == "startquiz1":
        print('a')
        questionnumber=1
        quiz1(query.message, context)
    elif query.data == 'startquizquest2':
        print('a2')
        questionnumber=2
        quizquest2(query.message, context)
    elif query.data == 'startquiz2':
        print('a2')
        questionnumber=2
        quiz2(query.message,context)

def main():
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("token", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dp.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(buttons))
    dp.add_handler(PollHandler(quizanswer1))
    dp.add_handler(PollHandler(quizanswer2))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Бот загружен.')
    main()
```